# show in ghci more or less picky about types

Tags: haskell, show, ghci

If I fire up ghci and type in a simple arithmetic expression, I usually get the expected result with no fuss

```
GHCi λ: 6 * 7
42
```

However, I am following the examples in a tutorial which are part of a cabal project. If I launch ghci within the project, e.g. `cabal repl Example` and try the same expression I get the following:

```
GHCi λ: 6 * 7

<interactive>:4:1: error: [-Wtype-defaults, -Werror=type-defaults]
    • Defaulting the following constraints to type ‘Integer’
        (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘print’ at <interactive>:4:1-5
        (Num a0) arising from a use of ‘it’ at <interactive>:4:1-5
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I am forced to specify the expression's type:

```
GHCi λ: 6 * 7 :: Int
42
```

I would like to understand what has likely made 'show' more picky in the tutorial's project, and if there is some way to get back to the convenience of 'sensible' defaults.

Comment: You likely compiled with `-Wtype-defaults` in your project, hence the error, which warns against type defaulting (and you also likely compiled with a flag that sees all warnings as errors).

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is related to how Haskell deals with number literals: one might think that a number like `6` has type `Int` (or `Integer`); however, if you ask ghci the type of `6` you'll get:

```
λ> :t 6
6 :: Num p => p
```

What this means is that `6` (or any number literal) is actually a value of a generic type `p` provided that `p` has a `Num` instance. Usually, thanks to type annotations, the compiler is automatically able to understand which numeric type you actually want:

```
plus2 :: Int -> Int 
plus2 x = x + 2
--            ^
--            since x has type Int (and Int has a Num instance)
--            2 is considered an Int as well
```

When the compiler can not understand what specific type you need for your type literal it will default to `Integer`, for example if you write:

```
print 2
-- print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
-- 2 :: Num p => p
```

Here both `print (2 :: Int)`, and `print (2 :: Integer)` are correct so the compiler defaults to `2 :: Integer`.
This defaulting behaviour might not always be ok (especially since `Integer`s are less efficient than `Int`s), so there is a GHC compilation flag that warns you every time this happens.

Your project's `.cabal` must have enabled the [`-Wtype-defaults`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html?highlight=wtype%20defaults#ghc-flag--Wtype-defaults) and the [`-Werror`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html?highlight=werror#ghc-flag--Werror) flags. If you remove `-Werror` you'll still see the warning about this defaulting behaviour but at least your code will execute; you can also remove the `-Wtype-defaults` to disable the warning.
If you do not see the `-Wtype-default` in your `.cabal` file it is because it can also be enabled by specifying one of this flags: [`-Wall`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html?highlight=werror#ghc-flag--Wall), [`-Weverithing`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html?highlight=werror#ghc-flag--Weverything).

*TL;DR* you should remove one of these compilation flags from the project's `.cabal` file:

- `-Wtype-defaults` (or `-Wall`/`-Weverithing`)
- `-Werror`

Comment: Slight point of precision: it defaults to `Integer` or `Double`, using the first in that list that meets all the constraints. This explains why e.g. `2/3` works but `length "ab"/3` doesn't.

Comment: Or append `-Wno-type-defaults` to your .cabal file e.g. `ghc-options: -Wall -Wno-type-defaults`